# upgrading python

Tags: python

Hi
I just want to install mercurial but for all versions it needs python 2.6, I tried to use .rpm file but the only thing I got is lots of lines full of error which tells: need old versions before 2.6 and after 2.5 which is installed on my linux. any help would be appreciated.
Bests

Comment: You may get better advice on installing linux applications on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Go to ActiveState and download their versions: https://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads

It's much easier than using the .rpms.

Answer (score 0):

Which distribution are you using? I would recommend you to upgrade your system to a newer version of your linux distro, whatever it is. Modern Linux distros are using at least python2.6 now.

If you do not want to upgrade your system with various reasons, ActiveState's python version as stated in Jasie's answer is good for your cause. It installs python in your system without breaking anything, just you have to add some lines in your .bashrc to force system find your ActiveState python installation before the system's python.

Another alternative would be installing earlier version of mercurial which supports the python version installed on your system. But I would not recommend you to do so..

Among these, my suggestion is upgrading your system to a merely "up-to-date" version, so that python2.6 or higher is installed on your system.